# How to map the array and store combined category?

Tags: jquery

i am getting the JSON response like this :

```
[
 {"IndexID":1,"IndexName":"Consumer Confidence Index(CCI)","IndexValue":34.79,"Month":10,"PercentageChanged":0,"Position":0,"Year":2011},
 {"IndexID":1,"IndexName":"Consumer Confidence Index(CCI)","IndexValue":34.25,"Month":11,"PercentageChanged":0,"Position":0,"Year":2011},
 {"IndexID":1,"IndexName":"Consumer Confidence Index(CCI)","IndexValue":33.58,"Month":12,"PercentageChanged":0,"Position":0,"Year":2011},
 {"IndexID":1,"IndexName":"Consumer Confidence Index(CCI)","IndexValue":32.64,"Month":1,"PercentageChanged":0,"Position":0,"Year":2012},
 {"IndexID":1,"IndexName":"Consumer Confidence Index(CCI)","IndexValue":36.92,"Month":2,"PercentageChanged":0,"Position":0,"Year":2012},

 {"IndexID":2,"IndexName":"Current Sentiment Index","IndexValue":47.42,"Month":10,"PercentageChanged":0,"Position":0,"Year":2011},
 {"IndexID":2,"IndexName":"Current Sentiment Index","IndexValue":47.55,"Month":11,"PercentageChanged":0,"Position":0,"Year":2011},
 {"IndexID":2,"IndexName":"Current Sentiment Index","IndexValue":47.01,"Month":12,"PercentageChanged":0,"Position":0,"Year":2011},
 {"IndexID":2,"IndexName":"Current Sentiment Index","IndexValue":45.01,"Month":1,"PercentageChanged":0,"Position":0,"Year":2012},
 {"IndexID":2,"IndexName":"Current Sentiment Index","IndexValue":47.32,"Month":2,"PercentageChanged":0,"Position":0,"Year":2012},

 {"IndexID":3,"IndexName":"Future Expectations Sentiment Index","IndexValue":29.63,"Month":10,"PercentageChanged":0,"Position":0,"Year":2011},
 {"IndexID":3,"IndexName":"Future Expectations Sentiment Index","IndexValue":28.81,"Month":11,"PercentageChanged":0,"Position":0,"Year":2011},
 {"IndexID":3,"IndexName":"Future Expectations Sentiment Index","IndexValue":28.09,"Month":12,"PercentageChanged":0,"Position":0,"Year":2011},
 {"IndexID":3,"IndexName":"Future Expectations Sentiment Index","IndexValue":27.59,"Month":1,"PercentageChanged":0,"Position":0,"Year":2012},
 {"IndexID":3,"IndexName":"Future Expectations Sentiment Index","IndexValue":32.67,"Month":2,"PercentageChanged":0,"Position":0,"Year":2012}

 ]
```

using each how can i make and store the data's like this:

```
var allData = [[for index id1],[for index id1],[for index id1]],[[for index id2],for index id2,],[[for indexid3],[for indexid3],[for indexid3]]];
```

**important : i don't know how may index values are in the data what i am getting it need to create all thorough dynamic.**

like so? it will help to draw the chart according to the category with different values.. any easy way to achieve this?

Comment: `for index id1` is array of objects?

Comment: yes, that is the array of object only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can think of is using two for loops

```
// first pass, extract all data and categorize it
var categories = [];

for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if(typeof categories[items[i].IndexID] == 'undefined') categories[items[i].IndexID] = [];
    categories[items[i].IndexID].push(items[i]);
}


// second pass, separate out each indexes to its own array in a big array
var results = [];

$(categories).each(function(i, n) {
   results.push(n);
});
```

Comment: where from are you getting itmes.length?

Comment: @3gwebtrain it's a standard property any javascript Array object has

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce it to a single object keyed on `IndexID`:

```
function keyOnId(prev, curr) {
    if(!(curr.IndexID in prev))
        prev[curr.IndexID] = [];

    prev[curr.IndexID].push(curr);

    return prev;
}

var dataObject = data.reduce(keyOnId, {});
```

You should now have an object `dataObject` looking something like:

```
{
  '1': [ {IndexID: 1, ...}, {IndexID: 1, ...}, ... ],
  '2': [ {IndexID: 2, ...}, {IndexID: 2, ...}, ... ],
  ...
}
```

Now, it's a simple matter of retrieving those arrays:

```
function arrayOfValues(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    return obj[key];
  });
}

var allData = arrayOfValues(dataObject);
```

**Edit:** Alternate solution -- this will only work if the `IndexID`s are numeric.

Reduce your array to a sparse array (will have undefined values for non-existing `IndexID`s, unless they are in sequence):

```
function sparseArray(prev, curr) {
     if(!prev[curr.IndexID])
         prev[curr.IndexID] = [];

     prev[curr.IndexID].push(curr);

     return prev;
}

var sparse = data.reduce(sparseArray, []);
```

Now, `filter` out only the truthy values:

```
var allData = sparse.filter(function(val) { return val });
```

**Update:**

[Fiddle of first approach](http://jsfiddle.net/srCcH/)

[Fiddle of second approach](http://jsfiddle.net/Pthd8/)

**Caveat:** Note that `Object.keys`, `reduce`, `map` and `filter` are parts of ECMAScript 5, and not available in IE, so you'll have to use an [es5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) for older browsers.

Comment: can you detail about prev, curr in both way of work? how can i pass all my arrays to function

Comment: That's what `reduce` does. See [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: can you use http://jsfiddle.net/ to explain further, i love your object based concept, but i unable to catch up!.. sorry!

Comment: I have updated the answer with a fiddle for each approach. I also found one error for each approach, I've corrected that.

Comment: Array reduce works like this: It will invoke the callback once for each item in the array, with the previous value (the value we are reducing all items to), the current item, the current index and the whole array. We are only interested in previous value and current value here. `reduce` also accepts an initial value (`{}` and `[]` respectively, above). We add some values to `prev` each time, and returning `prev` to the execution of the next item.